# jQuery jTable is blinking by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jtable

When I bind data to jquery-jTable by using ajax, the table is blinking by timer's period.

I used jquery.timer.js and jquery.jtable.js

Here is my javascript code.

---

```
function dispAlarmTable(){
    var d = new Date();
    $("#alarmTableContainer").jtable({
        ajaxSettings: {
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json'
        },
        actions:{
            listAction: 'http://localhost/alarm.php?t=' + d.getTime()
        },
        fields:{
            vmax:{title:'vmax'},
            imax:{title:'imax'},
            time:{title:'time'}
        }
    });
    $("#alarmTableContainer").jtable('load');
}
var timer = $.timer(function(){ dispAlarmTable(); }, 1000, true);
```

---

How can I avoid the blinking (white page and table, white page and table... by 1 second)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're recreating the table every second.

This involves clearing the previous contents of the element, re-initializing the basic structure, then waiting for the server to rely before re-populating it.

This also resets any user changes such as sorting.

Instead, you should update the data within the existing table instance.
The [reload function](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#met-reload) does this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you post a sample using reload function.